# How to name a file using text from another file?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file were each line contains a new customers info (email, name, title, bills) that will be substituted into a template file to create a file for customers whose bills exceed their payment. The problem I have is where the `?????` are located. I want to redirect the output to a filename named using the customers email, so far I haven't been able to do that. I am not sure how to go about this, I've tried multiple things but it hasen't worked.

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 set -e
  3
  4 if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
  5     echo "Illegal number of parameters. Usage;./test1.bash <mm/dd/yyyy>"
  6     exit 1
  7 fi
  8
  9 OUTPUT_DIR="Emails"
 10 details="p4Customer.txt"
 11 template="template.txt"
 12 date=$1
 13 if [ ! -d "$OUTPUT_DIR" ]; then
 14     mkdir -p "$OUTPUT_DIR"
 15 fi
 16
 17 gawk -f g2.awk -v date="$date" "$details" | while read detail;
 18 do
 19     sed "$detail" "$template" > "OUTPUT_DIR/??????"
 20 done;
```

awk file

```
  1 BEGIN{ FS=",";}
  2 {
  3     email=$1;
  4     fullname=$2;
  5     title=$3;
  6     n=split(fullname,A," ");
  7     name=A[n];
  8     amount_owed=$5;
  9     if($5>$4){
 10         printf "s_EMAIL_%s_;s_FULLNAME_%s_;s_TITLE_%s_;s_NAME_%s_;s_AMOUNT_%s_;s_DATE_%s_\n"    , email, fullname, title, name, amount_owed, date;
 11     }
 12 }
 13 END{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try putting another loop around the `gawk` command on line 17 and use the `cut` command that gives you the first field in the `$details` file. So lines 17-20 in your bash script would be replaced with:

```
# assume the first field is the email
for email in `cut -d, -f 1 $details`;
  do
  gawk -f g2.awk -v date="$date" "$details" | while read detail;
  do
    sed "$detail" "$template" > "OUTPUT_DIR/$email"
  done;
done;
```